# NTFS Removing Permissions

Tags: permissions, ntfs

Is there a simple way of disabling permissions on an NTFS filesystem?

I keep ending up with files with weird permissions.

I don't know what the default is, but maybe a script that just removes all users from a file, and sets the permissions for "everyone" to be everything?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could end up with bad side effects since some files and programs expect permissions. There are also things like the permissions are an important part of security for system critical files (ensuring ntkrnlos.dll isn't replaced, for example). I would look into using Filemon from SysInternals to figure out why you are having permissions errors instead of trying to ignore it.

Comment: +1 Good Answer. Vista and 7 especially are pedantic over permissions. Ignoring the problem is not solving anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what the default is, but maybe a script that just removes
> all users from a file, and sets the permissions for "everyone" to be
> everything?

This question is old, but I wanted to add an answer for those interested in resetting their security settings.

### For 2000/XP/2003, you can use the default Security template method.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949220#MethodA

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917925

**Note**
After security settings are applied, you cannot undo the changes without restoring from a backup. If you are uncertain about how to restore your security settings to the default settings, you must make a complete backup that includes the System State (the registry files).

Items that are reset include NTFS file system files and folders, the registry, policies, services, permissions, and group membership.

To restore your operating system to the original installation default security settings, follow these steps:

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then press ENTER.
> 2. In Windows XP, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>    **secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose**
> 3. In Windows Vista, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>    **secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb
>    /verbose**
>
> You receive a "Task is completed" message and a warning
> message that something could not be done. You can safely ignore this
> message. For more information about this message, see the
> %windir%\Security\Logs\Scesrv.log file.

### For Vista and up, Microsoft basically says you are SOL

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fixit4me/archive/2009/01/30/reset-security-settings-back-to-the-defaults-fix-it-live.aspx

There basically is no way to restore **all your security settings** back to default. You can get most of them back, however by using the old method.

Just as **warning**: Just note that it is unsupported and may **unknowingly break your system.** I guess that isn't an issue if it is already broken. I have and tested it and it is not for the faint at heart.

1. **If you choose to continue, follow the steps above.**
2. Next, you'll need to add all your user created User Accounts back into the User group.
3. Open an elevated command prompt
   a. Hit the   <kbd>Win</kbd> to bring up the Start Menu
   b. Type in **cmd** followed by   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   c. You'll know it is an elevated prompt because the Title bar says: **Administrator**.
   [image: Example Prompt]
4. type in **net user** to bring up a list of user accounts.
5. type in **net localgroup users** *accountname* **/add**, replacing *accountname*.